# PowerBI Dax - Filter with IF function. Create measure that avoids calculated columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have created a Dax code that counts up numbers of SKU in our company based on some filters. Right now i have the following code + helper columns in my dataset, that does the job correct.

```
Number of Active SKU = 
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Item'),
     FILTER('Item','Item'[Helpcolumn3] = 1 ),
    
     FILTER('SKUInfo',SKUInfo[StockKeeping] = "1" ),
    
        NOT('Item'[SKUStatus] IN { "P", "U", "X", "Z" } ) )
```

Helpcolumn3 consists of three calculated columns in my dataset, with about 1 million rows.

```
HelpColumn1= IF('Item'[SKULevel] IN {"1","2","3","4","5","6"} && 'Item'[SKUCode] IN{"A","B","C","D","G"},1,0)

HelpColumn2= IF('Item'[SKUCode] ="K", 1, 0 ) 

HelColumn3 = 'Item'[HelpColumn1] + 'Item'[HelpColumn2]
```

The reason behind the extra help columns were that i could not figure out how to incorporate this part into my measure. Im pretty sure it is possible, and i would like to avoid creating the three extra help columns with 1 millions rows each, since the data model is already quite big.

Any help as to how i can do this whitout creating the extra columns will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following please

```
_count=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Item' ),
    TREATAS (
        UNION (
            SUMMARIZE (
                CALCULATETABLE (
                    'Item',
                    CROSSJOIN (
                        { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
                        FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Item'[SKUCode] ), 'Item'[SKUCode] IN { "A", "B", "C", "D", "G" } )
                    )
                ),
                'Item'[SKULevel],
                'Item'[SKUCode]
            ),
            SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( 'Item', 'Item'[SKUCode] = "C" ), 'Item'[SKULevel], 'Item'[SKUCode] )
        ),
        'Item'[SKULevel],
        'Item'[SKUCode]
    ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] ), 'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] = 1 ),
    NOT 'Item'[SKUStatus] IN { "P", "U", "X", "Z" }
)
```

I am passing three filtered tables in this measure to do the count.

First set is the following block -> it counts whatever *combined elements* the data has for `'Item'[SKULevel]={ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" }` and `'Item'[SKUCode]={ "A", "B", "C", "D", "G" }`

```
TREATAS (
    UNION (
        SUMMARIZE (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                'Item',
                CROSSJOIN (
                    { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
                    FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Item'[SKUCode] ), 'Item'[SKUCode] IN { "A", "B", "C", "D", "G" } )
                )
            ),
            'Item'[SKULevel],
            'Item'[SKUCode]
        ),
        SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( 'Item', 'Item'[SKUCode] = "C" ), 'Item'[SKULevel], 'Item'[SKUCode] )
    ),
    'Item'[SKULevel],
    'Item'[SKUCode]
```

2nd set of table is the following block - which further filters the count of the first table to only `'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] = 1`

```
FILTER ( VALUES ( 'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] ), 'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] = 1 )
```

3rd set of table is the following block - which further filters the 2nd set to only `NOT 'Item'[SKUStatus] IN { "P", "U", "X", "Z" }`

```
NOT 'Item'[SKUStatus] IN { "P", "U", "X", "Z" }
```

In a nutshell, this returns `ROWCOUNT` for any items that has
`'Item'[SKULevel]={ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" }` and `'Item'[SKUCode]={ "A", "B", "C", "D", "G" }` but only `'SKUInfo'[Stockkeeping] = 1` and none with `[SKUStatus]="P", "U", "X", "Z"`

Comment: I seems to almost work. I added VALUES('Item') to this section for it to work.

`FILTER(  VALUES( 'Item' ), 'Item'[SKUCode] IN { "A","B","C","D","G" }  )`


However i am getting slightl different counts compared to my initial. It seems that this new measure is counting more rows than my initial method, with the difference being rather small. 

Do you have any ideas as to why that might be?